# JSON causes memory error

Tags: php, json

I have two file. One is index.php and the other is display.php.
Index.php contains a form and after submitting, it generates a json value and displays that in a textarea, so I might edit before I press the "generate" button and it redirects me to the display.php where a for loop generates a html template according to the posted son data. It works perfectly with up to 3 item, but if I use 4 or more, it drops me a fatal error with memory limit. As I still got errors after increasing the limit, I tried the following on the display.php:

```
ini_set('memory_limit', '-1');
set_time_limit(0);
```

After this, it drops me an error 503 - service unavailable.
I don't know what to do, I am asking your help.

index.php:

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>
    pre, textarea { background-color:#31495D;min-height:300px;color:white;margin-bottom:50px;padding:25px;width:100%;display:block;border-bottom:5px solid #A058B3; }
    .submit { padding:15px;background-color:green;color:white;border:none;font-size:12px;width:150px;margin:0 auto;margin-top:15px;margin-bottom:15px }
</style>
<?php

$json           = json_encode($_POST, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
echo "
<h2>JSON for template</h2>
<form action='display.php' method='post'>
    <textarea name='json'>$json</textarea>
    <input class='submit' type='submit' value='Generate Template'>
</form>
";

$json           = json_decode($json, true);


?>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    var max_fields      = 10; //maximum input boxes allowed
    var wrapper         = $(".input_fields_wrap"); //Fields wrapper
    var add_button      = $(".add_field_button"); //Add button ID

    var x = 1; //initlal text box count
    $(add_button).click(function(e){ //on add input button click
        e.preventDefault();
        if(x < max_fields){ //max input box allowed
            x++; //text box increment
            $(wrapper).append('<div><input type="text" name="url[]" placeholder="http://www.example.com/"/><input type="text" name="name[]" placeholder="Name"/><input type="text" name="subtext[]" placeholder="Subtext"/><input type="text" name="image[]"  placeholder="Image URL"/><a href="#" class="remove_field">Remove</a></div>'); //add input box
        }
    });

    $(wrapper).on("click",".remove_field", function(e){ //user click on remove text
        e.preventDefault(); $(this).parent('div').remove(); x--;
    })
});
</script>

<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>" method="post">
<label>Title of Block <input type="text" name="title"></label><br>
<label>Heading of Block <input type="text" name="heading"></label><br><br>

<div class="input_fields_wrap">
    <button class="add_field_button">Add More Fields</button>
    <div><input type="text" name="url[]" placeholder="http://www.example.com/"/><input type="text" name="name[]" placeholder="Name"/><input type="text" name="subtext[]" placeholder="Subtext"/><input type="text" name="image[]"  placeholder="Image URL"/></div>
</div>
<br><br>

    <input type="submit" value="Generate Code">
</form>
```

And the display.php

```
<?php   

$json = json_decode($_POST['json'], true);                  
$c = count($json);
$i = 0;
$rows = 3;


$content = "<table>";

for($i=0; $i < count($json["name"]); $i++) {


   $content .=

     '<td width="226" valign="top" style="padding:5px;padding-bottom:20px;" class="m-stack m-pad-b">
        <table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
           <tr>
              <td style="font-family:Helvetica Neue,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;font-size:22px;padding-bottom:5px; mso-line-height-rule:exactly; line-height: 18px; padding-top: 8px;">
                 <a href="'.$json['url'][$i].'" target="_blank" style="text-decoration:none;color:#0896ff; display:block;">
                 '.$json['name'][$i].'<br><span style="color: #7d90a6; font-size: 14px;">'.$json['subtext'][$i].'</span>
                 </a>
              </td>
           </tr>
           <tr>
              <td background="'.$json['image'][$i].'" width="226" height="226" valign="top" style="background-size:cover; background-position:center center; border-radius:6px 6px 0 0;" class="m-ufi-bg">
                 <!--[if gte mso 9]>
                 <v:rect xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" fill="true" stroke="false" style="width:226px;height:226px;">
                    <v:fill type="frame" src="'.$json['image'][$i].'" color="#7bceeb" />

                 </v:rect>
                 <![endif]-->
              </td>
           </tr>


        </table>
     </td>
     ';
     if($i == 3) { $content .= '</tr><tr>'; unset($i); $i == 0; } 

    } 
  echo "</table>";  

echo $content;
```

This is just an experiment for me, any suggestion / critique is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hello, thanks for coming. No, the two in this case is the same. I am just checking if $i is equal to 3, which can be divided by 3 as well.

Comment: thats fine, no problem :)

Comment: You are reseting `$i` to `0` so it never becomes greater than `count($json)` so your `for` loop becomes infinite.

Comment: Wow you are right. Please let me accept your answer so write one not just a comment :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are reseting `$i` to `0` so it never becomes greater than `count($json)` and your `for` loop becomes infinite